# How to create a sound using java directly to the speakers without intermediate mp3 file?

Tags: java, android

How to create a sound using java directly to the speakers without intermediate mp3 file?

I want to access the speakers directly.

I have tried

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" out.mp3
```

but that produces a file of about 40kB, which really, really looks like overkill for such a simple thing, so I want to skip the intermediate file and access the speakers directly.

A comment recommends "AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine()" which is available on my box, but not on my android device where I would like the sound to be played. So I have to clarify and add a new tag.

Comment: There are apis to send samples to a sound device. Take a look at `AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine()`

Comment: Android has [`AudioTrack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) for playback of PCM data.

Comment: @Michael I don't want to playback. I want to create audio sound directly. Something like programmatically write on a Canvas, only with sound instead of a screen.

Comment: That's not how it works. Just like a `Canvas` is an abstraction and not some direct access to the display hardware, there are abstraction layers in the audio domain too. As an Android app, the lowest-level entity would be an `AudioTrack` that you write PCM data to. Note that there's no need for a file to play back. In fact `AudioTrack` doesn't even directly support playback of files; it's meant for playback of audio data that you either have in memory or are generating on-the-fly.

Comment: @Michael I see, but I don't see clearly. Do you have a link where I could start with?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation I linked to, and maybe searching for some examples. I don't have any example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear by what you mean "create a sound using Java directly to the speakers". I'm assuming if a sound it sent to speakers, it is meant to be heard.

Sound that is created directly is usually done by creating PCM data (Pulse Code Modulation). On a desktop/laptop, once you have a file of PCM, you can play it back using `javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine`. On the Android system, you can stream PCM the data using `AudioTrack`.

When I think of creating sound, what usually comes to mind is a synthesizer. Creating PCM is a bit involved to explain, and I don't know if I'm even on the right track for what you are asking. With a little more direction, I'll add some more info if I am able to help.

Comment: As far as I can see, AudioTrack has to loaded with data *prior* to playing. I was looking for something like MysterialSoundManager.getSpeakerInterface().writeAndPlay(frequency,duration), which probably don't exist, so AudioTrack comes closest to my question. ***PCM*** and ***synthesizer*** are good keywords.

Comment: I can't find *MysterialSoundManager* on search. Do you have a link? I wrote a class called `AudioCue` that can be loaded directly with PCM. It takes optional frequency, vol & pan arguments and those parameters can be altered in real time. I didn't set it up for Android, but it should be possible to wrap/stream via an `AudioTrack` instead of a `SourceDataLine`. Perhaps it could be used in the way your are imagining or altered to become that? Java audio is pretty low level, very performant, need libraries for fancier stuff. https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue

Comment: MysterialSoundManager is named so because it is some mysterial class that would do the trick I'm looking for. Replace it with "foo" or "bar".

Comment: Looking for your keywords I have realized that what I have expected from my original question has really two parts "creating a sound" and, more into details of java/android, deliver it *directly* to the speakers. The first part alone is a whole wold for itself: creating a sound from primary elements.

Comment: I don't know that you can get more direct that a `SourceDataLine`. Maybe it would be helpful to take a look at how Java connects to the OS sound system as explained in this tutorial. "Accessing Audio System Resources" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html The actual lines/ports are dealt with at this level. Presumably AudioTrack is similarly close to the OS.